# how to create conditions in a dll that can be changed through the application running it

Tags: c#, c++, dll

My question is simple, I have a dll that I wrote in c++ and I'm calling it from a c# program. My question is if I can have a variable in the c# program that can be used in the dll that is written in C++ and change conditions inside the program when changing the variable. ex:

---

C#:

```
int z = 0;  //variable which i want to know if it can be used inside the dll.
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\example\libtest.dll")]  //path to the dll
public static extern void libtest(int x);  //
```

---

C++:

```
#include "C:\\Users\\app.cpp"   //path to the actual program
#include "C:\\Users\\Header.h"  //^^

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void libtest(int x) {

    myClass libtestx(x);
}
```

---

C++ (Header.h):

```
#pragma once

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(int x);
private:
    //bool z;
};
```

---

C++ (app.cpp):

```
void dosomething():
    //some method to do something
    while(z == 0){  //heres my question, can a var (z) inside the c# program set the conditions?
    //do something
    }
myClass::myClass(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        dosomething();
    }
    else if (x == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }

}
```

---

note that I just started learning these two languages and everything I have been learning and writing I learned by just asking questions and reading online so sorry If I sound stupid or my code is trash. I'll be very thankful for any help regarding my question or any tips that could help me improve. Thanks again.

Comment: Despite the frankly laughable premise behind this question, I don't think it deserves to be downvoted/closed. Its both well written and answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No (to your approach)

Lets ignore the difference in languages for the moment; the whole point of libraries is to be reusable across different consumers (programs). Thus the library knowing some detail of the application using it (like a variable) totally defeats the purpose.

Moreover, it creates a circular dependency, no compiler is going to go for that.

### Yes (applications can mutate library object state)

Programs do this *all the time* but they do it by creating the appropriate objects from the library and invoking methods on them (or mutating state, etc.). Say `myClass` had a method `setZ` that set its *local* `z` variable and that was called from the running application (it could even use the value of its (the programs) `z` variable!) Then subsequent calls to `myClass` would use that updated value.

On the whole, it seems like a revisit to OOP fundamentals and what libraries are for may be in order.